# Angular error not making sense

Tags: angular

i am trying to create a edit form using angular and for some reason [ngModel] keeps giving me error all though its reading the value and displaying it. little baffled by the behavior (very new to angular and learning)

below is my code :

1) HTML

```
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        {{title}}
      </div>
      <form #editProject = "ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)">
        <div class="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="projectName">Project Name</label>
                <input id="p_Name" type="text" name="project_name" class="form-control" 
                placeholder="Project Name" [(ngModel)]= "project.projectName" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"/>
            </div>
            <div class="button">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="updateProject()">Update</button>
            </div>
        </div>    
      </form>
  </div>
```

2) TS file:

```
import { Component,  Input, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import {Project} from '../../models/project';
import {ProjectService} from '../../services/project.service';
import { FormGroup,  FormControl, FormBuilder,  Validators, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit',
  templateUrl: './edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit.component.css']
})
export class EditComponent implements OnInit {
  public project: any;
  public projectForm: FormGroup;
  title = 'Edit Project';
  editProject: Project;
  isLoading = true;
  isSaving = false;
  i: any;  
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private projectService: ProjectService, private fb: FormBuilder) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.route.params);
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {this.i = +params['id']; });

    this.projectService.getProjectById(this.i)
    //.map(responseData => {this.project = responseData;})
    .subscribe(responseData => {      
      this.project = responseData;            
      console.log(this.project);
      this.isLoading = false;

    });    
  }
```

3) output:

[displays result "Database" but gives error too]

Comment: Can you please post the errors that you are getting ?

Comment: The value of `project` is not yet defined when the component is initialized. You could try something like: `[ngModel]="project?.projectName" (ngModelChange)="project.projectName = $event"`.

Comment: Aakriti...that worked.... i did not realize that project was not yet defined. thanks a lot for the help

Comment: You are welcome (I assume that the message was actually for me). :-) An alternative, if you want to keep `[(ngModel)]="project.projectName"`, is to initialize the variable when you declare it: `public project: any = { projectName: "" }`.

Comment: thanks agaian ConnorsFan...but the question here would be what if am using a datepicker instead of a textbox then how this will work?